# Only return result if a field is null for that result Django

Tags: mysql, django, database

I have a database in Django with several tables.

1 table is a *person*, 1 is a table with *departments* and 1 is a table of *volunteers*, which has a *many-to-many* relationship.

Here is the relevant parts of the *Department* model:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Navn',max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the relevant part of the *Person* model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Navn',max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is *Volunteer*:

```
class Volunteer(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    added = models.DateTimeField('Start', default=timezone.now)
    removed = models.DateTimeField('Slut', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    approved = models.DateTimeField('Godkendt af afdelingsleder',default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Frivillig"
        verbose_name_plural = "Frivillige"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person.__str__()

    def has_certificate(self):
        return self.person.has_certificate
```

I want to be able to select all active volunteers and people who are not volunteers.

This is a part of the code I used for the filter in the admin area:

```
if self.value() == 'any':
    return queryset.exclude(volunteer__isnull=True).exclude(volunteer__removed__isnull=False)
elif self.value() == 'none':
    return queryset.filter(volunteer__isnull=True).filter(volunteer__removed__isnull=False)
```

The removed field is a datetime field for when the volunteer stopped being a volunteer in that department.

My problem is that if a person is a volunteer in more than 1 department, it'll not return the correct result.

For any, it should return a person if at least 1 volunteer__removed is null.

For none it should return a person if none of volunteer__removed is null.

I've searched the documentation and all around Google and Stack Overflow, I've tried things like putting it in a for loop, but I couldn't get any of it to work.

Comment: Please add the models as well. It is not clear from your question what you are asking.

Comment: I've added the relevant models.

Comment: Nice of you to have added the code but please add  only the relevent parts. That's a lot of code to read and please do format it properly

Comment: I've tried to format it a bit better and select less code to include.

Comment: `return self.person.__str__()` this should be `return str(self.person)`

Comment: Thank you so much @BurhanKhalid. What is the benefits of using str(self.person) over self.person.__str__()?

Comment: One is the right way to do it :-)

Comment: You don't need the `person__isnull` check because the way you have defined your models, you cannot create a volunteer object where person (or department) is null.

Comment: Yes because a person can also not have a record in the volunteer table at all - if they are another type of person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it in the following way:

```
    if self.value() == 'any':
        return queryset.filter(volunteer__isnull=False).filter(volunteer__removed__isnull=True).distinct()
    elif self.value() == 'none':
        return queryset.filter(volunteer__isnull=True) | queryset.exclude(volunteer__removed__isnull=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to select all active volunteers and people who are
>   not volunteers.

Try approaching this from the `Person` model, each will have a [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) that is created by django automatically; what this means:

```
p.volunteer_set.all() # returns all volunteer object for this person
```

So, to find out which people are volunteers:

```
p.volunteer_set.filter(removed__isnull=False).exists()
```

If that is true, then it means that there it at least one record where removed is null is False.

Comment: Hmm that certainly seems to be a good solution for 1 person. However, then I'd have to somehow iterate over all persons and see if they are a volunteer - that seems expensive computation wise. Is there something in Django I'm not aware of?